# Problem Saving Silverlight 4 Business Application

Tags: .net, visual-studio, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

I’m trying to create a new project using the Silverlight 4 business application template in Visual Studio 2010 beta 2. When I click “Save All” after the project is created I get build errors such as:

- The project file "..\BusinessApplication1.Web\BusinessApplication1.Web.vbproj" was not found.   BusinessApplication1
- Unable to open module file 'C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\BusinessApplication1\Assets\Resources\ApplicationStrings.Designer.vb': System Error &H80070003&    C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\BusinessApplication1\Assets\Resources\ApplicationStrings.Designer.vb   1   1   BusinessApplication1

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't sound like you're doing anything wrong, it is Beta after all.  How did you install it?  Try re-installing it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, when the template builds the two projects, only the first project is being saved into your My Documents/Visual Studio 2008/Projects directory.  So, to fix this,

1. Go to *C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\*
2. Copy the BusinessApplication1.Web folder
3. Go to *C:\Users\XX\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BusinessApplication1*
4. Paste the copied folder
5. In Visual Studio, rename the current BusinessApplication1.Web project to anything
6. Click on File -> Add -> New Project
7. Navigate to *C:\Users\XX\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BusinessApplication1\BusinessApplication1.Web* and select the project file
8. Delete the old BusinessApplication1.Web project (the one you renamed earlier)
9. Right-click on *Solution 'BusinessApplication1' (2 projects)* and choose Properties
10. Go to Startup Project and set BusinessApplication1.Web as the single startup project